# Using calc() with a dynamic value?

Tags: css, calc

I am wondering if this is possible: I have a header that can contain a variable amount of text. Below that I have another element which I want to take up the remaining height of the page.

```
<div class="header row">
  <div class="title column large-5">Potentially very long text</div>
  <div class="menu column large-7">Menu items</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

Normally I would do this using calc, eg:

```
.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 75px);
}
```

Where 75px is the set height of `.header`.

But in this example, the `.header` element is dynamic and does not have a set height. Only a padding and font-size are set.

To complicate things, this also uses the Foundation Grid layout, which makes me nervous about using `display: table` (`.title` and `.menu` sit side by side on desktop, but stacked on mobile) .

Is there anyway to get the height of the dynamic header element (without resorting to JQuery)?

Comment: Can you use flexbox? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmaape

Comment: @MichaelCoker thanks! Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox and set `.content` to `flex-grow: 1` so that it will fill to grow the available space.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="header row">
  <div class="title column large-5">Potentially very long text</div>
  <div class="menu column large-7">Menu items</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a small pen to show the way to do this using flex box, it involved changing your markup a bit:

css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 250px; // whatever you want here
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

So the content will always take the available space inside the content div.

check the whole pen: http://codepen.io/anshul119/pen/yMYeLa

hope this helps.